# Can we run a code developed using fragments on device which does not support it?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is it possible to run a code developed using fragments on device which does not support it?

Please reply.

Comment: use fragments from support library.

Comment: Use android-support-v4.jar library to use fragments on devices having Android version below 3.0. But there is one condition that the device should be Android 2.2 and above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the [support library's fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html), then yes.